# credentials check for non-domain accounts or local user accounts

Tags: powershell

[image]I request your help for to check the Windows local user account and 
password working fine or not.

Issue details: I am unable to read/use when username name pattern like to login with local user account '.\administrator'. In option 1, the credentials only work either username@domain or domain\user. In option 2, I am unable to read '.\administrator'.

Note: My script is working fine with user name pattern like 'administrator' or 'local\administrator'. Only it is not working when entering like '.\administrator'.

Below is the code I used.

Option 1:(attached the screen shot)

```
      Write-Host 'Enter your crdentials with username and password'
$Credentials  = Get-Credential

 try
{

Invoke-VMScript -VM jumpbox1 -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "(gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter 'netconnectionid is not null').netconnectionid" -GuestCredential $Credentials -ErrorAction stop | out-null


Write-Host 'Crdential works'
}

catch
{

Write-Host 'Invalid Crdential works'

}
```

Option 2:

```
    $Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the username: '
    $GuestPasswd = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Password: ' -AsSecureString 
    $Password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($GuestPasswd))

   try
{

Invoke-VMScript -VM jumpbox1 -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "(gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter 'netconnectionid is not null').netconnectionid" -GuestCredential $Credentials -ErrorAction stop | out-null


Write-Host 'Crdential works'
}

catch
{

Write-Host 'Invalid Crdential works'

}
```

Error:- cred02.ps1
Enter the username: : .\administrator
Invoke-VMScript : 6/12/2019 1:50:03 PM    Invoke-VMScript        A specified parameter was not 
correct:
At cred02.ps1:36 char:1
+ Invoke-VMScript -VM jumpbox1 -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "(gwmi Win3 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-VMScript], InvalidArgument
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_VmGuestServiceImpl_RunScriptInGuest_ViError,VMware.VimA 
   utomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.InvokeVmScript

Enter the username: : ".\administrator"
Invoke-VMScript : 6/12/2019 1:51:44 PM    Invoke-VMScript        Failed to authenticate with 
the guest operating system using the supplied credentials.
At cred02.ps1:36 char:1
+ Invoke-VMScript -VM jumpbox1 -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "(gwmi Win3 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-VMScript], InvalidGuestLogin
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_VmGuestServiceImpl_RunScriptInGuest_ViError,VMware.VimA 
   utomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.InvokeVmScript

Comment: The code in your second snippet is broken. Please [edit] your question and fix that. Copy/paste the code from your script exactly as it is. Do not wrap it in arbitrary places.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I re-copied the code once again. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Now the code in both snippets is broken. Did you copy that from a terminal or from a script?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried `-GuestCredential` parameter?

Comment: Thank you for the reply robdy. I added the screen shot. I tried as i mention earlier it is working for 'administrator' not for '.\administrator'

Comment: hi friends, requesting for suggestion/code help. Thank you.

Comment: Again, please **DO NOT** wrap your code in arbitrary places. We cannot help you when the code you post in your question is even more broken than the code in your script.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply Ansgar Wiechers. I am sorry to say, i didn't use the code option. I hope this time, i did correctly. Thank you for your time and support.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I hope this time, i use correct options. Thank you for your time and support.